Ways to invert complicated matrix formulas
I have two somewhat complicated matrix formulas that convert the mean vector and covariance matrix for a certain variable, $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, into the mean and second moment matrix of the transformed variable, $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Psi \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. We also have the constraint $\|\mu\|=1$. I want to know if there's some way to try to solve for $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ given known $\gamma$ and $\Psi$, other than gradient descent.
For example, the formula giving $\gamma$ is as follows:
\begin{align}
\label{eq:taylor2}
  \gamma & =
    \frac{\mu}{(\mu^2 + \hat{z})^{\frac{1}{2}}} +
    \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{-3  \mu \odot \hat{z}}{( \mu^2 + \widehat{z})^{5/2}} \right)
    \odot \mathrm{diag}(\Sigma) + \nonumber \\
    &\quad \frac{1}{2}
    \left( \frac{3 \mu}{4( \mu^2 + \widehat{z})^{5/2}} \right) \odot \mathrm{var}(z) +
    \left( \frac{ \mu^2 - \frac{1}{2}\hat{z}}{( \mu^2 + \hat{z})^{5/2}} \right)
    \odot \mathrm{cov}(x,z)
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
  \hat{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n = \mathbf{1} (\mathrm{tr}(\Sigma) + \mu^T  \mu) -  \left( \mathrm{diag}(\Sigma ) + \mu^2 \right)
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
  \mathrm{var}(z) \in \mathbb{R}^n &=  \mathbf{1} \left(2 \mathrm{tr}( {\Sigma}  {\Sigma})  +
  4 {\mu}^T  {\Sigma}  {\mu} \right) - 
  2 \left( 2 \, \mathrm{diag} \left(  {\Sigma}  {\Sigma} \right) 
    - \mathrm{diag} \left(  \Sigma \right)^2 \right) - \nonumber \\
  &\quad 4 \left( 2 \mu \odot  \Sigma  {\mu} -
     \mu^2 \odot \mathrm{diag} \left( \Sigma) \right) \right)
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{cov}(x, z) \in \mathbb{R}^n = 2 ( \mu^T  \Sigma - \mu \odot  \mathrm{diag} (\Sigma))
\end{equation}
The divisions, multiplications and the powers of vectors are all element-wise (element-wise products are indicated by $\odot$). The formula for $\Psi$ is simpler, but of a similar flavor (I omit it here since I don't think it adds much, but can add it if requested).
As stated above, I am interested in the problem of obtaining the $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ that generate an observed $\gamma$ and $\Psi$. For this I have been using gradient descent with autodifferentiation in pytorch, which works fine, but for same cases it struggles a bit to converge, it takes some computing time, and some choosing of optimization parameters such as learning rate, optimizer and loss that I'd like to get rid of.
Since all the elementary operations in the problem seem simple, I was wondering whether there is some other way to solve this problem that does not involve optimization. I guess I could try to actually manually derive the equations that solve for $\Sigma$ and $\mu$, but with how messy these expressions look, I'm not sure that's a promising path. Although maybe there's also tools to aid with this that I ignore?
Edit:
Upon request, I add an example of the Python code for the formulas.
import torch
import numpy as np

def prnorm_mean_taylor(mu, covariance):
    """ Approximated expected value of the generalized projected gaussian
    Y = X/(X'X)^0.5, where X~N(mu, covariance).
    ----------------
    Arguments:
    ----------------
      - mu: Means of normal distributions X. (nDim)
      - covariance: covariance of X. (nDim x nDim)
    ----------------
    Outputs:
    ----------------
      - YExpected: Expected mean value for each projected normal.
          Shape (nDim)
    """
    variances = torch.diagonal(covariance)
    ### Get moments of variable v (||X||^2 - X_i^2) required for the formula
    meanV = v_mean(mu=mu, covariance=covariance)
    varV = v_var(mu=mu, covariance=covariance)
    covV = v_cov(mu=mu, covariance=covariance)
    ### Get the derivatives for the taylor approximation
    dfdu2Val = dfdu2(u=mu, v=meanV)
    dfdv2Val = dfdv2(u=mu, v=meanV)
    dfdudvVal = dfdudv(u=mu, v=meanV)
    ### 0th order term
    term0 = f0(u=mu, v=meanV)
    ### Compute Taylor approximation
    YExpected = term0 + 0.5*dfdu2Val*variances + 0.5*dfdv2Val*varV + dfdudvVal*covV
    ### If B is not None, project back to original basis
    return YExpected


def v_mean(mu, covariance):
    variances = covariance.diagonal()
    # If weights are not None, scale variances and mu
    # Compute the expected value of X'BX
    meanX2 = torch.sum(variances) + torch.einsum('i,i->', mu, mu)
    # Compute E(X_i^2)
    meanXi2 = mu**2 + variances
    # Subtract to get E(X'BX - B_i*X_i^2)
    meanV = meanX2 - meanXi2
    return meanV


def v_var(mu, covariance):
    # Compute the variance of X'X
    varX2 = 2 * qr.product_trace(covariance, covariance) + \
        4 * torch.einsum('i,ij,j->', mu, covariance, mu*weights)
    term1 = 2 * torch.einsum('ij,ji->i', covariance, covariance) - \
        covariance.diagonal()**2  # Repeated terms in the trace
    term2 = 2 * torch.einsum('i,ij,j->i', mu, covariance, mu*weights) - \
        mu**2 * torch.diag(covariance) * weights # Repeated terms in (mu'Cov mu)
    # Subtract to get variance
    varV = varX2 - 2*term1 - 4*term2
    return varV


def v_cov(mu, covariance):
    covV = 2 * (torch.einsum('i,ij->j', mu, covariance) - \
        mu * torch.diagonal(covariance))
    return covV


def f0(u, v):
    """ First term of the Taylor approximation of f(u,v) = u/sqrt(u^2 + v),
    evaluated at point u,v"""
    f0 = u / torch.sqrt(u**2 + v)
    return f0


def dfdu2(u, v):
    """ Second derivative of f(u,v) = u/sqrt(u^2 + v) wrt u,
    evaluated at point u,v."""
    dfdu2 = - 3 * u * v / (u**2 + v)**(5/2)
    return dfdu2


def dfdv2(u, v):
    """ Second derivative of f(u,v) = u/sqrt(b*u^2 + v) wrt v,
    evaluated at point u,v. b is a constant """
    dfdv2 = 0.75 * u / (u**2 + v)**(5/2)
    return dfdv2


def dfdudv(u, v):
    """ Mixed second derivative of f(u,v) = u/sqrt(u^2 + v),
    evaluated at point u,v."""
    dfdudv = (u**2 - 0.5 * v) / (u**2 + v)**(5/2)
    return dfdudv


By $\odot$ do you mean Hadamard product, i.e., componentwise product ?

Yes, I thought it was clear from stating that multiplications are element-wise, but I added the clarification just now.

Even if your question aslks for an alternative approach, could you provide your Python program in order to check (my) understanding of your formulas ? Besides, what are the order of magnitude of $m, n$ ?

Just added the Pytorch code for the $\gamma$ formula. It's divided into subfunctions that I didn't make explicit in the formulas. I also didn't include the code for the second moment matrix. There is no $m$, that was a typo in the question (see edited). The special case $n=3$ is of special interest, but $n$ can go from 2 to 100's.
